# Laravel subdomain route problame

Tags: laravel, routes, subdomain

**I am working on a subdomain system on laravel.**

suppose my main domain name is: `test.test`
and my subdomain name is: `subdomain.test.test`

Now, the problem is, when I use the main domain route in sub-domain blade file like:

```
<a href="{{route('profile')}}">Profile</a>
```

then, it should generate links like `test.test/profile`
but, it's generating links with subdomain like: `subdomain.test.test/profile`

**Now, How can I solve this problame?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use relative path instead of absolute [using `route()` helper third parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route).

```
<a href="{{config('app.url')}}{{route('profile',[], false)}}">Profile</a>
```

Comment: I just removed "/" after {{config('app.url')}}. Now, <a href="{{config('app.url')}}{{route('profile',[], false)}}">Profile</a> work for me. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Spatie Multitenancy](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/), when i do route('home'), he return back the url with the actual domain.